# Why if $p (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is polynomial on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $p (x) \neq 0$ is satisfied by open dense set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, baire-category

I have problems in seeing what exactly is the all point of *first category* and *second category* sets. Finally, I've found a reference (Bredon's "Topology and Geometry") that introduces the topic in a way that is sort of comprehensible.

Still, there is a piece in that reference that I do not get:

> *"Often, one is interested in a condition on points of a space that is satisfied by an open dense set of points. For example, if $p (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is a polynomial function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the condition $p (x) \neq 0$ has this property, and a special case of that is the determinant function on square matrices."*
>   (Bredon - "Topology and Geometry" p.57)

I have no clue why this is the case.

Is there somebody who can enlighten me?
As always, thank you for your time.

Comment: Well for one variable, the zeros of a polynomial are a discrete set. For two variables, the zero set is a curve of some kind... maybe it's true in general that that set is a hypersurface of codimension 1. That would imply that the complement is an open, and at least my geometric intuition tells me the surface is nowhere dense in the complement. I'm not sure if you can make this into a proof - it's just an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Actually I am not at all into polynomials, hence every reference to them looks a bit cryptic to me. Btw, notice that this is literally a small example, and the author doesn't say anything more, but still I wanted to get it (also to get a better grasp of nowhere denseness, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The author certainly means that this holds whenever $p$ is a *non-zero* polynomial. The set of points $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $p(x) \neq 0$ is open because its complement is the preimage of the closed singleton $\{0\}$ by the continuous map $p$, which is therefore closed. It is dense because a polynomial is analytic, and an analytic function that is zero on some neighborhood is zero everywhere on the connected component of that neighborhood.

Comment: It might be better said as $p \not \equiv 0$.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for the answer. I am recently working on polynomial with coefficients from the field of rational functions. Do you know where I can find similar results (density of zero sets) related to this type of polynomials?

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that $p \neq 0$, as otherwise this is false. First, let's see why the set $ NZ = \{x \mid p(x) \neq 0\}$ is open. The polynomial $p$ is a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so the inverse image of a closed set is closed. The point set $\{0\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed, so its inverse $Z = \{x \mid p(x) = 0\}$ is also closed. Our set $NZ$ is just the complement of $Z$, and hence must be open.

To see why $NZ$ is dense, let's take a point $z = (z_1, z_2, \cdots, z_n) \in Z$ and find  points $x \in NZ$ arbitrarily close to it. We can do this by induction on the number of variables. If $n=1$ this is a classic result: a nonzero polynomial is zero at a finite set of points. For $n=2$, rewrite $p(x_1,x_2) = \sum_{i=1} ^{d} x_{1}^{i}q_{i}(x_2) + r(x_2)$ by factoring out $x_1$. By hypothesis either some $q_{i}(x_2)$ is not zero or we can reduce to $p = r(x_2)$, and then $p$ is a polynomial in one-variable whose zero set is just the zero set on $\mathbb{R}$, times the real line. Now plug in the value $x_2 = z_2$.

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{d} (x_1)^{i}q_{i}(z_2) + r(z_2)$$

If this is a non-constant polynomial in $x_1$ then near the zero $x_1 = z_1$ there will be values for $x_1$ giving us something non-zero (as it has only one variable), and we will be done. Otherwise all $q_{i}(z_2)$ are zero. But since these are polynomials in one variable we can replace $z_2$ with a nearby value $z_{2}'$ and make one of these polynomials nonzero. Then near $(z_1, z_{2}')$ is a point $(z_{1}',z_{2}')$ making $p$ nonzero, and again we are done.

For the inductive step on $\mathbb{R}^n$ we would rewrite, where again we assume some $q_{i}$ is nonzero else we automatically reduce ourselves to the $n-1$ case.

$$p = \sum_{i=1}^{d} x_1^iq_i(x_2, \cdots, x_n) + r(x_2, \cdots, x_n)$$

Then plugging in the values $x_2 = z_2, \cdots, x_n = z_n$, we either get a single-variable polynomial in $x_1$ with a nearby nonzero point, or we tweak the values to $x_2 = z_{2}', \cdots, x_{n} = z_{n}'$ to make some $q_{i}$ nonzero, which we know we can do by induction, and the find a nonzero point with those coordinates.

Comment: +1...Equivalently,  with $r=q_0$ in your last equation for $p$: For $n>1$, if $S=int p^{-1}\{ 0 \} \ne \phi$ then $S\supset \prod_{i=1}^n J_i$ where each $J_i$ is a non-empty real  interval. Then for any $(x_2,...,x_n)\in  \prod_{i=2}^n J_i$ we have $x\in J_1\implies \sum_{i=0}^d x^i q_i(x_2,...,x_n)=0$  which implies  that the interior, in $R^{n-1}$, of $q_i^{-1} \{ 0\}$ covers $\prod_{i=2}^n J_i$ .Which by the inductive hypothesis, implies that each $ q_i$ is identically $0$.....You had a typo, writing $p=(\sum _ix^nq_i)+r$ which I corrected  from $x^n$ to$x^i$.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers explained, $S:=p^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ is open because $p$ is continuous. What follows is yet another proof that $S$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^n$ when $p$ is nonzero:

Case I: $n=1$. The fundamental theorem of algebra gives that any nonzero $p$ will have at most $\operatorname{deg}(p)$ real roots, and so $S$ is the complement of a finite set, which is necessarily dense.

Case II: $n>1$. Suppose $S$ is not dense, meaning there exists $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ for which $p$ evaluates to $0$ on a neighborhood of $x_0$. We will show that $p$ is necessarily the zero function. Take any $x_1\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then there exists $\epsilon>0$ for which $q(t):=p(x_0+t(x_1-x_0))=0$ for every $t\in[0,\epsilon)$. Since $q(t)$ is a single-variable polynomial with infinitely many roots, it follows from Case I that $q$ is the zero polynomial, and so $p(x_1)=q(1)=0$.